# Webdriver hangs in new window with “about:blank” in address bar, transitioning to file download dialog

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I need some help for the following issue using Webdriver, Java, and Firefox.

In the testing, when clicking on a link, 
1) it will often open a new window with a normal web page.  OR
2) occasionally, it will open a new window with “about:blank” in address bar; after 20 to 60 seconds the new window will disappear and a file download window will appear.

Because the URL is rewritten for SEO, there is no way to check the URL before or after clicking on the link to determine whether the link connects to a normal web page or a downloadable file.

In both cases, 
    driver.getWindowHandles().size() == 2,
so I can switch to the new window successfully using the following statements in order to check whether a certain WebElement exists in new window.
    for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }

But if the link connects to a downloadable file, the execution will hang for any of the following methods:
    findElement(By.xpath(“//html”));
    findElements(By.tagName(“body”));
    getCurrentUrl();
    getPageSource();
    getTitle();
    getWindowHandle();

getWindowHandles() always returns 2 while new window with “about:blank” in address bar presents before it is replaced by the file download dialog.  It occasionally throws a NoSuchWindowException exception; but most of the time, it just hangs.  I tried the Explicit and Implicit Waits to no avail.

Many thanks
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the following preference?  (This will get rid of the download dialog all together)

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that.  This suppresses the file download dialog, but the "about:blank" new window still presents for 20 to 60 seconds before it disappears.  The testing execution hangs in this new window, even after it disappears.